# Firebase storage stopped working after September 19 update. Looks like firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com is no longer supported

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

My app is suddenly unable to write to my Firebase storage. When I go to my firebase console I now see a warning

> On September 19 we made an important security improvement to Cloud Storage for Firebase. If your app is experiencing issues or you simply want to learn more, visit the Firebase FAQ.  [Learn more](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/index#storage-accounts)

From following the link it sounds like if you setup your Firebase Storage before September 19, 2022 it created a cloud storage bucket for you named `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com.` but with the new changes the previously-linked Cloud Storage buckets named `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com.` are no longer supported.

I have very little experience working with Cloud storage, So my question is how do I fix this? What steps do I need to take to get firebase storage working properly again?

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ link tells you pretty explicitly what to do, so I recommend following the steps described there.

If you like a more visual guide, this comment on a GitHub issue on this same error message might help too: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9588#issuecomment-1258294970

If you're still having trouble after following these guides, edit your question to [show what you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, it's unlikely we can help any better than the FAQ and the GitHub link.